# What's wrong with the following program?

Tags: haskell

what's wrong with this code?

```
module Main where
import System.Environment
main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    putStrLn ("Hello, " ++ args !! 0 ++ ", " ++ args !! 1)
    putStrLn(add (read args !! 0) (read args !! 1))
add x y = x + y
```

Here are the error messages:

```
main.hs:8:15:
    No instance for (Num String)
      arising from a use of `add'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num String)
    In the first argument of `putStrLn', namely
      `(add (read args !! 0) (read args !! 1))'
    In the expression: putStrLn (add (read args !! 0) (read args !! 1))
    In the expression:
      do { args <- getArgs;
           putStrLn ("Hello, " ++ args !! 0 ++ ", " ++ args !! 1);
           putStrLn (add (read args !! 0) (read args !! 1)) }

main.hs:8:25:
    Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `[Char]'
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: [String]
    In the first argument of `read', namely `args'
    In the first argument of `(!!)', namely `read args'
```

Comment: Well, what *is* wrong with it? Errors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`read args !! 0` should be `read (args !! 0)` and `add x y = x +` should be `add x y = x + y`. Also `putStrLn` takes a string only, so use `print` instead which also prints numbers.

---

However, seeing you are new to haskell. I rewrote part of your program to demonstrate a more haskellish way.

```
main = do
    (arg0:arg1:restArgs) <- getArgs
    putStrLn $ "Hello, " ++ arg0 ++ ", " ++ arg1
    print $ add (read arg0) (read arg1)
add = (+)
```

I think it looks a bit cleaner now. Note that it's most often considered bad practice to use `!!`.

Comment: You need to remove the `x y` from the pointfree version of `add`. Good answer otherwise, +1.

Comment: That's right amigo. Edited it, sorry for not bothering to compile the code. :)

Comment: I think the real reason `!!` is considered bad practice is because it has undesirable error handling.  I might also point out that while your use of pattern matching on the list is more concise than using `!!`, it has the same dangerous error behavior.

Comment: Yes. There are many reasons `!!` is bad practice, I just wanted to keep it short. The more one studies haskell and thinks about it, the more enlightened conclusion you can draw. As for the asker, I saw it as most appropriate to just give a quick-hint, rather than a complete elaboration on why `!!` is bad practice. About error handling, I think the error messages will be clearer with pattern matching.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a little elaboration on the error messages and the solution given. Looking at the first error:

```
    No instance for (Num String)
    ...
    In the first argument of `putStrLn'
```

This might be a bit unclear. Have a look at the type signature for putStrLn:

```
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
```

So, putStrLn is a function that takes a String and evaluates to an IO action. However you have directly **tried to pass putStrLn some expression like (x + y), which is a number**, and Strings are not numbers (in Haskell terms, its type signature is (Num t) => t).

The solution given above suggests using the print function instead:

```
print :: (Show a) => a -> IO ()
```

The difference between 'print' and 'putStrLn' is that **print can take anything showable**, which includes numbers.

Next up:

```
    Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `[Char]'
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: [String]
    In the first argument of `read', namely `args'
```

This says **the compiler expected a String as the first argument to read, but saw a list of Strings**. Looking at the original code:

```
read args !! 0
```

In Haskell, function application has highest precedence, so the compiler basically reads your code like so:

```
(read args) !! 0
```

(note in particular that the application of read binds higher than the use of the !! operator). Hopefully it should be clear now that **read has been applied to all of args**.

As your intention seemed to be to read the first element of args, you need to use parentheses like so:

```
read (args !! 0)
```

Hope this makes the error messages a little more understandable!